# simplify multiple variables that are similar

Tags: jquery

i want to simplify this into a smaller chunk of code just clean code and not repeat myself.
i have a small project i am working on and it has a parallax thing going on but in-between each 'parallaxed' slide there is a 'white' slide. so i have a white menu button at beginning, but when it gets to a 'white' slide you cant see it. so i made this little function. obviously could be better.

```
function changeColor (){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var slide2Check = $('.slide2').offset().top-$(window).scrollTop();
    var slide3Check = $('.slide3').offset().top-$(window).scrollTop();
    var slide4Check = $('.slide4').offset().top-$(window).scrollTop();
    var slide5Check = $('.slide5').offset().top-$(window).scrollTop();

    if (slide2Check < 25 && slide3Check > 25 || slide4Check < 25 && slide5Check > 25 ) {
        $('.nav-button').css('border', '2px solid #407C73');
        $('.nav-button span').css('color', '#407C73');
    } else {
      $('.nav-button').css('border', '2px solid white');
      $('.nav-button span').css('color', 'white');
    }
  });
};
```

ok so i took both of your suggestions and did this. what do yall think?
thanks so much!

```
var $window = $(window),
    $nav_button = $('.nav-button, .nav-button span'),
    allCheckedSlides = [],
    navIsColored = $nav_button.hasClass('nav-colored'),
    allSlides = $('section');

    function checkPosition(){

      var addColorClass = allCheckedSlides[1] < 25 && allCheckedSlides[2] > 25 || allCheckedSlides[3] < 25 && allCheckedSlides[4] > 25;

      for (var i = 0 ; i <= allSlides.length; i++){
        allCheckedSlides[i] = positionCheck($(allSlides[i]));
      }

      function positionCheck(x){
        if (!x.length){
            return 0;
          }
        return x.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
      };

      if ($nav_menu.hasClass('slide-in')){
        $nav_button.removeClass('nav-colored');
      } else if (addColorClass) {
              $nav_button.addClass('nav-colored');
      } else {
              $nav_button.removeClass('nav-colored');
          }
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a new class selector to your slides `slide-even` or `slide-odd`. I have added comments to the code explaining what it does, its relatively straight forward:

```
function changeColor (){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var slidesEven = $('.slide-even'); //will be an array of html results
        var slidesOdd = $('.slide-odd');  //will be an array of html results

        for (var i = 0; i < slidesEven.length; i++) {
            var slideEvenCheck = computeCheckVal($(slidesEven[i])); //must wrap slidesEven[i] in jQuery object to use offset and $ functionaltiy

            var slideOddCheck = 0;

            //**add a conditional check if even slides do not always have a complimentary slidesOdd[i]**
            if(slidesOdd.length -1 <= i)
                slideOddCheck = computeCheckVal($(slidesOdd[i])); //must wrap slidesOdd[i] in jQuery object to use offset and $ functionaltiy


            if (slideEvenCheck < 25 && slideOddCheck > 25) {
                $('.nav-button').css('border', '2px solid #407C73');
                $('.nav-button span').css('color', '#407C73');
            } else {
                $('.nav-button').css('border', '2px solid white');
                $('.nav-button span').css('color', 'white');
            }
        }
    });
};

function computeCheckVal($slide) {
    if (!$slide.length)
        return 0;

    return $slide.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
}
```

Comment: thanks Brian. i used both of your suggestions to create this.

Comment: Sure, glad to give you some ideas ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since the scroll event can trigger many many times a second the biggest improvement you can make is to cache the elements outside of the event handler so you aren't having to search the dom constantly ... which is the most expensive part of your code.

Also, if the changes have already been made and the conditionals are still the same there is no point in doing extra unnecessary dom manipulation.

I would also suggest simply toggling a class on the nav-button and set your styles using css

```
// store all the elements once, instead of constantly searching the dom
var $window = $(window),
    $slide2 = $('.slide2'),
    $slide3 = $('.slide3'),
    $slide4 = $('.slide4'),
    $slide5 = $('.slide5'),
    $nav_button = $('.nav-button');

$window.scroll(function () {
    var slide2Check = $slide2.offset().top - $window.scrollTop(),
        slide3Check = $slide3.offset().top - $window.scrollTop(),
        slide4Check = $slide4.offset().top - $window.scrollTop(),
        slide5Check = $slide5.offset().top - $window.scrollTop(),
        addColorClass = slide2Check < 25 && slide3Check > 25 
                       || slide4Check < 25 && slide5Check > 25,
        navIsColored = $nav_button.hasClass('nav-colored');

    if (addColorClass) {
        // only make changes if they havn't already nbeen made
        if (!navIsColored) {
            $nav_button.addClass('nav-colored');
        }
    } else {
        if (navIsColored) {
            $nav_button.removeClass('nav-colored');
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: thanks charlietfl. i used both of your suggestions to create this.